# Apache Ignite: errMsg=Out of memory

Tags: ignite

Inserted 1M records in single partition to cache and then trying to retrieve them.
I have 3 ignite nodes each having 32G memory and 8 core.

```sql
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to execute map query on remote node [nodeId=f02e1c83-52af-4ea7-ab70-4e48540e5321, errMsg=Out of memory.; SQL statement:
SELECT KEY, _VAL FROM IGNITEVALUE WHERE KEY BETWEEN 'ParkedEvents/T45/' AND 'ParkedEvents/T45/|' AND AFFINITYKEY='Book12174583-T45' ORDER BY KEY ASC [90108-197]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.arcesium.trinity.cache.TrinityCachePerfMain.main(TrinityCachePerfMain.java:85)
Caused by: javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to execute map query on remote node [nodeId=f02e1c83-52af-4ea7-ab70-4e48540e5321, errMsg=Out of memory.; SQL statement:
SELECT KEY, _VAL FROM IGNITEVALUE WHERE KEY BETWEEN 'ParkedEvents/T45/' AND 'ParkedEvents/T45/|' AND AFFINITYKEY='Book12174583-T45' ORDER BY KEY ASC [90108-197]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridReduceQueryExecutor.fail(GridReduceQueryExecutor.java:235)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridReduceQueryExecutor.onFail(GridReduceQueryExecutor.java:214)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.onMessage(IgniteH2Indexing.java:2186)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.lambda$start$22(IgniteH2Indexing.java:2125)
```

How can I fetch those 1M records?

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, your server nodes ran out of memory. One suggestion is to make sure [lazy loading is enabled](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/perf-and-troubleshooting/sql-tuning#lazy-loading) otherwise it might have to copy all the data to the Java heap. You might also want to increase the amount of Java heap space.

Having said that, you're not going to get the best out of Ignite using it in client-server mode like this. Don't copy the data, instead, send the code to the data using [compute tasks](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/distributed-computing/distributed-computing).